# trigger button inside a repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button inside a repeater control and I would like to disable it. I tried something like this...

```
if (Session["USER_ID"] == null)
{
   //disable download button and     
}
else
{
   //enable download button
}
```

This is the button I want to enable and disable `btnTEST`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
     OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
   <ItemTemplate>            
         <asp:Image ID="image" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image_src")%>' runat="server"  />                           
         <asp:Button ID="btnTEST" runat="server" Text="Click Me!" CommandName="testme" Enabled="False" />                          
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I am unable to use this:

```
btnTest.Enabled = True;
```

It doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the button is inside the Repeater-control it will be dynamically generated as many times as there are items in the datasource databound. So you have to enable/disable the button on the [repeater ItemDataBound-event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) as so:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnTEST");

        if (Session["USER_ID"] != null)
        {
            btn.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Ps. No need to disable since the button is disabled by default.

Comment: it doesn't work 
i noticed that it doesn't even go in to the if statement

Comment: `if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
Session["USER_ID"].ToString();
`
but the label doesnt even display the userID

Comment: Did you attach this this method to the repeaters ItemDataBound-event?

Comment: `<asp:Button  ID="btnTEST" runat="server" 
                         Text="Download" CommandName="testme" Enabled="False" />`
that's what i have at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Because the button is in a repeater. You need to disable the button in the itemdatabound. I suggest you to add something like this in the code behind:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
       base.OnInit(e);
       Repeater1.ItemDataBound += (s, ev) =>
       {
           if (ev.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem && ev.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item)
                    return;
             var btnTest= ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button) ev.Item.FindControl("btnTEST"));
             btnTest.Enabled = Session["USER_ID"] != null;
        };
 }
```